# c# pass by ref not working?

Tags: c#

Whats going on here? Why isn't the = working? It's not a value type so it should be passing by reference right?

```
void func()
{
    Vector2 a = new Vector2(1, 0);
    equal(a);
    // a is now (1, 0) not (0, 0)
}

void equal(Vector2 a)
{
    a = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vector2` is `Struct` and struct type is a `value type` not reference. use `ref` keyword passing by reference

Comment: No, use `ref` to pass the value by reference. It doesn't pass it "as a reference type" - it's worth keeping the concepts of "reference type" and "pass by reference" very separate in your mind.

Answer (score 6):

C# passes arguments by value by default hence it's only assigning to `a` within the `equal` method.  You need to use a `ref` parameter here if you want pass by reference

```
void func()
{
    Vector2 a = new Vector2(1, 0);
    equal(ref a);
    // a is now (0, 0) as expected
}

equal(ref Vector2 a) 
{ 
  a = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

Comment: +1. To confuse the issue, it should be noted that with non-value-type objects (called reference types), it's a reference that is geting passed by value ;-)

Comment: @JaredPar, sorry for the edit, I intended to edit mine and clicked too quickly...

Comment: @JamesHill no worries. Edit looks fine

Answer (score 3):

Cause the reference to a is passed as value and not as reference, so you are modifying a '
local' a.

correct would be:

```
void equal ( ref Vector2 a)
```

hth

Mario

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing by reference. To do that, you'll need to use the `ref` keyword

```
void func()
{
    Vector2 a = new Vector2(1, 0);
    equal(ref a);
}

void equal(ref Vector2 a)
{
    a = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the *reference* you would need to pass by ref to ensure the *reference* changes.

```
void func()
{
    Vector2 a = new Vector2(1, 0);
    equal(ref a);
}

void equal(ref Vector2 a)
{
    a = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

I suggest reading about [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) and [this](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html).

Comment: He'd need to use ref either way.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a value type or not - assigning to a parameter isn't going to change the value of the *argument* unless you use `ref`.

Comment: @alan2here - Yes. It is a struct.

Comment: this happens for classes as well though... pass-by-ref is default behavior.

Comment: @EoinCampbell - You mean pass-by-value.

Comment: Based on the comments here almost no one knows what they are talking about.

Comment: See my answer, where I peice together the various bits of others answers to tell the full story. The real villan here is the c# developers or .net developers not going further in making things consistant and well designed, and less C like. I think lots of people will fall into traps like this.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
void func()
{
    Vector2 a = new Vector2(1, 0);
    equal(ref a);
}

void equal(ref Vector2 a)
{
    a = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A copy of the reference to a is being passed to the equal method. The code inside equal is changing the memory location pointed to by the copy.
See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx#vclrfpassingmethodparameters_example4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#vclrfpassingmethodparameters_example4) for details.

Just to be clear: The Vector2 object is not being copied, the variable a is being copied when it is passed to the method.

Answer (score 0):

A reference type can be passes by value or by reference. The default
is to pass by value which is what your code sample does.

When a reference type is passed by value, you can modify the
state of the object but you cannot change the reference itself so it would
refer to a new object. To do that you must pass by reference.

```
void equal(ref Vector2 a)
{
    a = new Vector2(0, 0);
}
```

Here is a direct link to the part of my online .NET training which
illustrates all cases with animation and code samples: http://motti.me/cf

I hope this helps!

Motti